# C preprocessor replacement not working

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VAR cc

int main(void) {
    int ccc = 9;
    printf("hell loo %d", VARc);
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding of this code means that anywhere the preprocessor finds `VAR`, it will replace it with `cc`, hence the `printf` will have a proper defined variable `ccc`, but the code errors out. Can someone please help

---

**EDIT 1**

Error that I am getting is

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16: error: ‘VARc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:16: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:16: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: please post your error message

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? This really looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: PSkocik's answer below is correct, but this is more or less an abuse of the preprocessor. If you tell us what your _actual_ use case is, then we might suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 10):

That won't work. The preprocessor works on whole tokens, not strings.

If you want concatenation, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define VAR(End) cc##End // ## does token concatenation inside a pp macro

int main(void) {
    int ccc = 9;
    printf("hell loo %d", VAR(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that was not working is:

Tokenization precede preprocessing in other words identifying tokens from the preprocessing file comes before  macro expansion.

As **CPP is greedy**, it will consider `VARc` as a single token relating to identifier category and which is different from `VAR` in macro definition. That's why it cannot be replaced.

So one of solution is to use concatenation or create another macro for `VARc`.